# Where is the PHP path in CentOS 6.5 droplet?

Tags: php, cron, centos, digital-ocean

Unfortunately I do not have access to the droplet via console, only by Vesta panel and I need to set up cron job. 
However, I can not find the right path to PHP. Now that command line looks that and it does not work:

```
/usr/local/vesta/bin/php5 -c /home/admin/web/ -q /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/crop_scripts/cron.php
```

Please tell me what options instead of "/usr/local/vesta/bin/php5" I can try?

Comment: maybe /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php  or /usr/local/bin/php5

Comment: can you run console commands through vesta? you could try to locate php with "which php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does this code show when you access it through your web server (assuming `exec` call is allowed)

```
<?php
$output = array();
exec('which php',$output);
var_dump($output);
```